# Bitblt window capture fails on MEmu (android emulator)

Tags: c#, android-emulator, screen-capture, bitblt

Try to capture the MEmu emulator's window with bitblt() (or Printwindow() - have the same issue) but can't grab the content of the window, only the background picture.

[Captured window:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuQqQ.png)

[Original window:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3rPf.png)

Tried with every program related window handlers manually (spy++, inspect etc..) and programmatically (enumwindows()).
Also tried with SRCCOPY and SRCCOPY | CAPTUREBLT options without success.

Do you have any suggestion what else to try or the Bitblt function doesn't work with every kind of windows and need to use different technique?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this issue?

Comment: After a lot of research I ended up the problem is probably these functions only can read the OpenGL rendered window's (like most of the android emulators) front buffer, but the data is in the back buffer, so need to do a dll injection to read and process the data from there.. It went too far, couldn't achieve it.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the reply! I just figured it was also possible to capture that using `adb screencap`, so this is what I'm going to do now. :)